# How to rewrite this code from jquery to pure js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this ajax request currently written in Jquery which I’d like to rewrite in pure javascript.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'assets/php/sendToTelegram.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        myJson : localStorage.getItem('sendCart'),
        myFormJson : localStorage.getItem('arrayForm')
    }
});
```

Could anyone head me in the right direction?

Comment: Use the `fetch` API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked into how jQuery `$.ajax` works, and how AJAX in javascript in general functions?

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```js
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var json = {
    myJson: localStorage.getItem("sendCart"),
    myFormJson: localStorage.getItem("arrayForm")
}
xmlhttp.open("POST", "assets/php/sendToTelegram.php");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(json));

var json = {
    myJson: localStorage.getItem("sendCart"),
    myFormJson: localStorage.getItem("arrayForm")
}
```

Or with the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):

```js
fetch("assets/php/sendToTelegram.php", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(json)
});
```

The Fetch API is built in, so you don't need any libraries.

Comment: Nothing works. You made a small typo in the variable, but that's not the point. I do not understand why. "data" in jquery converts the data' to a query string, so does JSON using JSON.stringify. But still, something is not right